# aws cloud9 use custom php-fpm on 127.0.0.1:9000

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, cloud9

I have installed cloud9 on a custom centos7 with a custom httpd.conf + php7.

httpd.conf

```
listen 36000
<FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/myC9/www"
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/myC9/www">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I can edit these files in cloud9 and see them externally as expected `myUrl.com:36000/blah.php`

to preview inside cloud9 I have tried

```
select .php script tab -> right click -> run this file
```

but an error is reported. It may be I have the current working directory incorrectly set.

If I try to change the current working directory from 
    ~/myC9/www
to
    /home/ec2-user/myC9/www
I get `Directory does not exist`. But this directory is the same as `~/myC9/www`

How do set the preference for a custom runner to use the custom `httpd.conf`+`127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: Is this 2 problems, fixing apache+fpm and defining a runner? What error do you get when hitting `myUrl.com:36000/blah.php`, you can just set the preview url.

Comment: No, just one problem. The custom httpd+php7 works as expected as a normal webserver. I just cannot seem to trigger it from inside cloud9 to preview files.

Comment: Just change the preview url, runners are not good for servers which are running already ;p (php inbuilt, nodejs etc).. to change current working directory, your need to change it in .c9 start up with the -w switch